# Graphics PipelineView Transform

Tags: math, matrix, graphics, 3d, transformation

Trying to get a better Understand on View Transform, using Right Handed Rule. If anyone can help clarify the given slide. For example what is C standing and why is it negative also why is an inverse applied to the matrix, and finally what is the simplest form of these matrices concatenated. Thank you for your time and help!
[image]

Comment: (Cx, Cy, Cz) are the coordinates of the camera (i.e. the point from which rays are cast) as far as I understand. Try http://3dgep.com/?p=1700 for more details

Comment: why are they negative is it cause in camera view the Z is inverse?? If so how does that effect the Cx and Cy to be negative as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assume we have a 3D point `P = (Px,Py,Pz)` in real world coordinates
- Let `u` be the vector pointing "left" (as seen by the camera)
- Let `v` be the vector pointing "up" (as seen by the camera)
- Let `w` be the vector pointing "forward" (as seen by the camera)
- `u`, `v` and `w` are orthogonal, and I assume that we already normalized them (so now we have an orthonormal base)
- Let `C = (Cx, Cy, Cz)` be the location of the 'eye' of the camera

If we were to manually translate `P` to camera coordinates, it would have been done like this:

- Find the location relative to the camera `Pc = P - C`
- We can find the `u` (/`v`/`w`) component of the point by computing the dot product of `u` (/`v`/`w`) and `Pc`
- So the coordinates of `P` as seen by the camera are `(<Pc,u>,<Pc,v>,<Pc,w>)`, where `<x,y>` denotes the dot product of `x` and `y`

And this matches exactly to the given matrices:

```
| ux  uy  uz  0 |   | 1  0  0 -Cx |   | Px |
| vx  vy  vz  0 | X | 0  1  0 -Cy | X | Py |
| wx  wy  wz  0 |   | 0  0  1 -Cz |   | Pz |
|  0   0   0  1 |   | 0  0  0   1 |   |  1 |

  | ux  uy  uz  0 |   | Px - Cx |
= | vx  vy  vz  0 | X | Py - Cy |
  | wx  wy  wz  0 |   | Pz - Cz |
  |  0   0   0  1 |   |  1      |

  | <Pc,u> |
= | <Pc,v> |
  | <Pc,w> |
  |      1 |
```

So basically, the big matrix you have there is indeed the one that converts points from absolute coordinates to camera coordinates

Comment: But just another quick question shouldnt the matrix be added as so for the last part ??  ux*(Px-Cx) + uy*(Py-Cy)+ uz*(Pz-Cz) + 1

Comment: `<Pc,u>` was indeed a short form for writing `ux*(Px-Cx) + uy*(Py-Cy)+ uz*(Pz-Cz)` (note that I don't have a `+1` in the last coordinate since the matrix has a `0` in it's last column of that row)

Comment: Sorry one question why is your first row in the matrices  ux,uy,uz,0 and not like the example ux, vx, wx, 0 ??

Comment: Note the transpose on the matrix as it's written in your slides

Comment: i know that A^-1 = A^T, But why take the Inverse in the first place? Is this applied to every rotation or it just for the view transform.

Comment: The matrix with `u`, `v` and `w` in it's columns is a rotation from coordinates back to absolute coordinates, and it's transpose (which is also it's inverse, as you said) is from absolute coordinates to view coordinates. I believe they wrote the view->absolute matrix with a transpose, because at least for me this is indeed the one which is easier to understand without doing the math. But again, it doesn't matter